# 'AssemblyTitle' attribute in the .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, .net-assembly

What is the practical use of the `AssemblyTitle` attribute? MSDN says that it specifies a description for an assembly and that the assembly title is a friendly name which can include spaces.

Visual Studio asks for the assembly name in the properties window of the project along with the default namespace. There is an `AssemblyName` attribute but it describes an assembly's unique identity in full (i.e., culture, etc.). I don't see how `AssemblyTitle` differs from `AssemblyProduct`.

I used the IL Disassembler to see how Microsoft uses `AssemblyTitle`. I discovered that in **mscorlib.dll**, `AssemblyTitle`, `AssemblyProduct` and `AssemblyDefaultAlias` are all set to `"mscorlib.dll"`.

In conclusion, what I really would like to see are practical examples of the use of `AssemblyTitle`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Product can comprise of several assemblies.

All of the assemblies will have a single product name and individual assemblies will have their own titles.

**`AssemblyProduct = "MyProduct"`**

**`AssemblyTitle = "MyProduct.Utilities"`**

and for another assembly

**`AssemblyTitle = "MyProduct.Security"`**

the assembly title is also used in the explorer file properties etc. `File > Properties > Details` tab

```
File Description = AssemblyTitle
Product name = AssemblyProduct
```

Comment: And so if I have a single-assembly product I should just skip it or give the two the same value?

Comment: giving it values is better than skipping. If your single assembly is a product in itself, they can be same. typically even for single assembly products (e.g. Product name = 'Johns Pizza') your assembly title = "Johns Pizza Web App".. and finally you can name them the same as well.. nothing bad will happen ;)

Answer (score 57):

[AssemblyTitle] is a pretty big deal, it is directly visible when you right-click on the assembly and use Properties + Details.

An example to make it more visible.  Let's start with this AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("AssemblyTitle")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("AssemblyDescription")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("AssemblyConfiguration")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("AssemblyCompany")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("AssemblyProduct")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("AssemblyCopyright")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("AssemblyTrademark")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: Guid("7da36bdf-39fb-4a4d-b98c-ecefd99b155a")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("5.6.7.8")]
```

And look at the properties of the file:

[image]

Some annotations to this:

- Note how [AssemblyDescription] is misleading, it is actually the Title you see in the property sheet.
- Description, Configuration and Company are not displayed.  You probably want to merge the company name into the visible Copyright.  Description and Company are actually present in the unmanaged version resource but Windows just doesn't display it.
- [AssemblyCulture] is special, it is used by satellite assemblies for localization
- [Guid] is special, it sets the type library guid if you create a [ComVisible] assembly
- [AssemblyVersion] is extraordinary special, a really big deal in the .NET Framework.  That it is not displayed is a major hangup.  You can see it in XP, not in later Windows versions.  A strong consideration is to make the [AssemblyFileVersion] the same value.
- The displayed "Product version" is the same as the "File version".  That's not great either, you want to add the [AssemblyInformationalVersion] attribute to fix that.

It is quirky, the Windows group and DevDiv didn't always work together well.

Comment: Do you think it makes sense to have the AssemblyTitle the same as the assembly name in Properties->Application->Assembly name?

Comment: Only if you can't come up with a better description.  Surely you can.

Answer (score 11):

The `AssemblyTitle` also appears as an application's name in the task manager (Windows 10), e.g. in the "Processes" tab or the "Fewer details" view.

[image]

Comment: It appears that when `AssemblyTitle` is blank, this shows the executable name. Or maybe that's only for processes it identifies as "background". Not completely sure.