# Should assembly guid attribute vary for different target framework builds of the same .NET library?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, guid, csproj

I am developing a .NET library in C# which has to address a wide set of target frameworks. I want to produce a nuget package that would install correctly according to the settings of the target project.

In order to achieve that, I am using multiple .csproj files. Each of them is addressing a particular target framework (for example MyLibrary.net45.csproj would create the binaries in `bin/*/net45`, MyLibrary.netstandard1.2.csproj would create the output in `bin/*/netstandard1.2`, and so on). Then I create a single nuget package with the outputs of the above projects.

At this stage, the different .csproj files re-use the same AssemblyInfo.cs file and thus use the shared settings there.

I've been wondering whether it is correct for all the different target frameworks to use the same value for the `[assembly: Guid("...")]` attribute, or should each target framework binary be built with its own distinct one?

Comment: It is not very correct.  However, it doesn't get a use, only real role it plays that I know of is to provide the LIBID for the type library generated by Tlbexp.exe.  Duplicate guids corrupts the registry.  But that only matters if you use [ComVisible(true)] in your library.  You perhaps ought to be a lot more concerned about versioning and the unmanaged VERSION resource that the assembly linker generates, that matters a wholeheckofalot more.  Readily visible in the Details property sheet in Explorer btw, you could not generate a decent title.  YMMV.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23145471/17034

Comment: @HansPassant grateful to see your comments, always educating and in place. You should probably write that as an answer. I'm afraid I did not understand the unmanaged VERSION thing (I've not done much com-visibility stuff I have to admit) and also, what could go wrong with the AssemblyTitle attribute, I believe I use that one correctly (as per the linked post). Should I worry if all my different per-target dlls share the same AssemblyTitle (I bet I should not). Cheers :)

Comment: I just can't provide you with a guarantee that you will never regret this, sorry.