# Is there any reliable (even standardized) approach to creating a .NET library that supports multiple target frameworks simultaneously?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, projects-and-solutions, target-framework

I understand this is quite a general question but I've not been able to find a reliable resource on solving the following scenario, nor it has been in one place. So I decided to ask here in the hopes to help others struggling with the same issue:

As a developer of .NET components I want to support a wide variety of .NET target frameworks. This topic had become quite important for me as of the recent explosion of target framework variants when **dot net core** and the **dot net standard** have been introduced.

So, imagine I am writing a C# library `MyLib` (that I would refer to as "product") which compiles to the `MyLib.dll`. I want to support the different range of target frameworks: `net35`, `net40`, `net45`, `netstandard1.2` and etc. Therefore I create builds (MSBuild or csproj files) for each target framework and bundle them together in a single nuget package, respecting the [nuget guidelines for the lib folder structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks). Thus the product can be obtained from a single build artefact -- the nuget package.

For each target framework version I try to utilize its features and benefits and provide pollyfills for the lower versions or strip some features. In general the point is that the "product" is usable regardless of the consuming project's target framework -- I mean the nuget package for `MyLib` should install correctly, and the appropriate dll should be referenced.

So, a few questions arise:

- Is it correct to share the same assembly version info across the different builds? Like re-using the same `AssemblyInfo.cs` file?
- Which assembly attributes should not be shared between my builds? I have started [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778309/should-assembly-guid-attribute-vary-for-different-target-framework-builds-of-the) in regards to the `[assembly: Guid("...")]`] attribute. Other people are [displaying concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144872/assemblytitle-attribute-in-the-net-framework) of the `[assembly: AssemblyTitle("...")]` attribute as well, while in a different context.
- Is there any good or standardized approach of organizing a solution to support the described above build outcome. Do most projects out there really fend for themselves in achieving this?

My own way so far is to use a separate .csproj file per target framework for the same "product", but as the development progresses, it could become tedious to support multiple projects, even so as the target framework count is quite significant now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Therefore I create builds (MSBuild or csproj files) for each target framework and bundle them together in a single nuget package.

If you are using the new csproj "SDK" format from Visual Studio 2017 then you don't even need to do that - it supports multiple target frameworks. For example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFrameworks>net451;netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This project supports both the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and NETStandard1.3.

This automatically creates conditional compilation symbols so you can do things like `#if NET451` or `#if NETSTANDARD1_3` so you can conditionally apply code, if needed. You can likewise do this in the .csproj itself for including nuget packages for only one framework. The [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/d72ae17a22ebb408d947843ad58fce512eff74e8/Dapper/Dapper.csproj#L17) project has an example of this in their .csproj file.

Using the new `dotnet` cli, you can use `dotnet pack` to package it all up in to a nuget package.

Comment: Nice! I've been using similar thing already for the .netstandard flavours of my projects, yet in a wrong way -- a single csproj file per framework. Does this work well for older framework versions, as I am still supporting `net35`? Also, I've been having issues importing external msbuild targets, some property groups would not be respected unless I add the `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` to the root element of the imported target. The latter causes MSBuild warnings. Have you any recommendation for that?

Comment: @IvayloSlavov You can conditional include based on framework and even share the includes across csproj files using a props file. See [`Directory.build.props`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/d72ae17a22ebb408d947843ad58fce512eff74e8/Directory.build.props) and the [`Dapper.sln`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/d72ae17a22ebb408d947843ad58fce512eff74e8/Dapper.sln).

Comment: 1. Sure, it even works with .NET 2.0. [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/515fee0b52c9f581f39de788e58832c11fccf3b2/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj#L3) has an extremely thorough example of supporting a ton of platforms. 2) let me look in to that one.